# compare two dates in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to angular 6 ,Here I need to compare to date inputs and find the greatest one.

```
input 1 : 2018-12-29T00:00:00
input 2 : Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Here I received the **input 1** from mssql database and the **input 2** from the material datepicker .

while compare this two dates as below I got false.

```
console.log(mMagazineObject.From < mMagazineObject.To ? true : false);
```

is there any possibility to compare these two date formats .If yes please help me to fix this .

Comment: It's not about angular it's about JavaScript. You could consider MomentJS to use for working with dates

Comment: You should convert both to date objects, and then you can use .valueOf() to get the milliseconds since unix epoch. That will be enough to do a proper comparison.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use getTime

```
if (input1Date.getTime() < input2Date.getTime())
```

Note that if your dates are in string format, you first need to parse them to Date

Answer (score 10):

Angular has builtin formatDate method so you can use it to format your date and also compare it simply like below code:

In your component.ts file:

```
   date1 = formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');
   date2 = let FToday = formatDate(datecomingfromdb,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');

   if(date1>date2){
     console.log('---date1 is greater----');
    }else{
     console.log('---date2 is greater-----');
    }
```

hope this helps and you can read more in Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

Answer (score 2):

finally I found the solution.

```
console.log(mMagazineObject.From < this.datePipe.transform(mMagazineObject.To, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ? true : false);
```

Comment: please be aware that adding "? true : false" doesn't do anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Date.parse(input)` is the best idea for if the APIs change. This provides timestamps, numbers which you can compare easily with the math comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all way to compare 2 dates but below is the best built-in angular method for compare 2 dates.

```
if (formatDate(FromDate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US') > formatDate(ToDate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US')) 
{
console.log('---Fromdate is greater----');
}
else
{
console.log('---Todate is greater----');
}
```

Here, first argument of formatDate is date input, second argument is format of date, third argument is locale.